# Xcode 6 : Place buttons side by side

Tags: button, xcode6, cgpoint

In my game I currently have the 2 buttons placed one on top of the other, I would like to move the 'restore' button next to the 'remove' button.

I cannot work out where I am going wrong.

This is a snip of the code where one button is on top of the other.

```
if (!self.adsDisabled && kAD_REMOVAL_IAP_ENABLED)
{
    self.removeAdsButton = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"RemoveAds"];
    [self.removeAdsButton setPosition:CGPointMake((self.removeAdsButton.frame.size.width / 2) + 10, self.size.height - (self.removeAdsButton.frame.size.height / 2) - 10)];
    [self.gameOverOverlay addChild:self.removeAdsButton];

    self.restorePurchasesButton = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"RestorePurchases"];
    [self.restorePurchasesButton setPosition:CGPointMake((self.restorePurchasesButton.frame.size.width / 2) + 10, self.size.height - (self.restorePurchasesButton.frame.size.height / 2) - 10 - self.removeAdsButton.size.height - 10)];
    [self.gameOverOverlay addChild:self.restorePurchasesButton];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this?

```
[self.restorePurchasesButton setPosition:CGPointMake((self.restorePurchasesButton.frame.size.width / 2) + 10 + (self.removeAdsButton.frame.size.width), self.size.height - (self.restorePurchasesButton.frame.size.height / 2)];
```

Comment: yes thats basically what i had (Tried yours, same problem), Xcode returns errors everytime i try. When it doesn't return an error the button is no where to be seen.